# BI Publisher - Display Data Horizontally

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I have the following data model:

```
<SALE_LIST>
    <SALE>
        <YEAR>2010</YEAR>
        <ITEM>100001</ITEM>
        <AMOUNT>1,199.00</AMOUNT>
    </SALE>
    <SALE>
        <YEAR>2010</YEAR>
        <ITEM>100002</ITEM>
        <AMOUNT>1,200.00</AMOUNT>
    </SALE>
    <SALE>
        <YEAR>2012</YEAR>
        <ITEM>100001</ITEM>
        <AMOUNT>1,899.00</AMOUNT>
    </SALE>
    <SALE>
        <YEAR>2012</YEAR>
        <ITEM>100003</ITEM>
        <AMOUNT>1,649.00</AMOUNT>
    </SALE>
    <SALE>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
        <ITEM>100004</ITEM>
        <AMOUNT>2,199.00</AMOUNT>
    </SALE>
    <SALE>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
        <ITEM>100005</ITEM>
        <AMOUNT>3,199.00</AMOUNT>
    </SALE>
</SALE_LIST>
```

In rtf template, using `for-each` to display all `YEAR`:

```
<?for-each:SALE?>
<?YEAR?>
<?end for-each?>
```

Normally, the result will be displayed vertically, like this:

```
2010
2010
2012
2012
2013
2013
```

**How to display the result horizontally, like this**:
`2010` `2010` `2012` `2012` `2013` `2013`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?for-each@inlines:SALE?>
<?YEAR?>
<?end for-each?>
```

If you want to print the values in horizontal table columns, you will need dynamic columns. You will have to use:

```
<?split–column–header:name?>
<?split–column–data:name?>
```

If you have installed BIP Word addon on your windows system, you will have the sample templates provided by Oracle. Go down to you BI Publisher Desktop folder, and check the samples folder. On my system, the location is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\Template Builder for Word\samples\RTF templates\Advanced\Dynamic Columns
```

There will be a `Dynamic Data Columns.doc` file there, which explains neatly how to do this.

Comment: you're cool. So how could I put the result to table, each cell is a year.

Comment: Thank you for your information, it's too much useful.

Comment: Hi, I have a requirement where the Split header should have a header and its plain text. Not related to any element. When I just add a header to the existing column, the static header is applied to only first data column, I want it to be common across all the columns.

 _ _ _ _ _ _
|   |common |
|   |_ _ _ _ _ |
| _|_|_|_|_|_ |

Comment: @TusharBanne, you can hardcode the plain text in the header. After <?split–column–header:name?>, just give <?'HARDCODE'?> ,where name is the node by which want to split,