# BI Publisher / PeopleSoft Security Roles Report

Tags: user-roles, peoplesoft, bi-publisher

Hey I am trying to create a report to display in a matrix type format the navigations and permissions that a user has. I already have a query set up that correctly gets the path associated with each user. I am having trouble creating the XML / BI Publisher template.

The staging table has the format

ROLE  |   COMPONENT   |  DISPLAYONLY  |   NAVIGATION PATH

and I want to convert this into a table where it may look something along the lines of

PATH  |   COMPONENT   | ROLE1  | ROLE2 | ROLE3 | .... | ROLE N |

where it has all of the users access rights given a certain path. Any guidance is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  It might not hurt to review the help guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  As is, your question is pretty broad.  More details, especially on what you have already tried, are a good way to get some helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your request is to print data horizontally, which has been answered previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633191/bi-publisher-display-data-horizontally/38635653#38635653). This can be done via RTF templates, and there are samples provided by oracle here : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\Template Builder for Word\samples\RTF templates\Advanced\Dynamic Columns`, where you have installed BIP Word Addon.